# Java script Заморозка колонки сложных таблиц

Tags: javascript

Нужно было написать скрипт который "заморозит" первые несколько колонок таблицы при её прокрутке влево. Таблица сложная в том плане что имеются объединение ячеек в первых колонках как по вертикали, так и по горизонтали. Написал скрипт который по сути выполняет эту задачу, но вот браузер (Chrome) начинает жутко висеть. Может кто подскажет как ускорить. С JS дружить начал совсем недавно....

```
  /*Реакция на событие window.onscroll*/
    function cloneTab(arg, oldBody) {

       arg.style.display = oldBody.getBoundingClientRect().left<3?"":"none";
       arg.style.top = oldBody.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
     }

     /*основная ф-ция клонирует tbody из таблицы, делает лишние ячейки display:none,
       в обратном порядке обходим ячейки в связи с тем что в колонках которые нужно заморозить
       могут быть объединения ячеек по вертикали и горизонтали*/

    function freezColumn(countCells) {

      if (document.getElementById('freez') !== null) {return false;}  
    //если уже есть созданная скриптом таблица выходим из ф-ции ничего не создавая
      var tab = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];   
      var tabBackground = getComputedStyle(tab, "").background;
      var oldBody = tab.tBodies[0];
      var newBodyes = oldBody.cloneNode(true);
       //следующая функцция пройдется по ячейкам таблицы и сделает их видимыми или невидимыми
    for(r=0; r<newBodyes.rows.length; r++) {
        for(c=newBodyes.rows[r].cells.length-1, i=newBodyes.rows[0].cells.length-countCells; i>0; c--, i--) {
          newBodyes.rows[r].cells[c].style.display='none';
        }
      }
      newBodyes.style.position = 'fixed';
      newBodyes.style.top = tab.tBodies[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
      newBodyes.style.left = "0px";
      newBodyes.style.zIndex = 0;
      newBodyes.id = "freez";
      newBodyes.style.marginTop="0px";
      newBodyes.style.marginLeft="0px";
      newBodyes.style.display="none";
      newBodyes.style.background = tabBackground;
      tab.appendChild(newBodyes);
      var newBody = document.getElementById('freez');
      window.addEventListener("scroll", function(arg) {cloneTab(newBody, oldBody);});  
    //вешаем нашу функцию на событие
    return true;
    }

    freezColumn(3);
```

Comment: @visionp, В след раз, чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: событие scroll - очень частое, сделайте его через clearTimeout/setTimeout ну и если таблиц несколько... вы для каждой обрабатываете scroll, сделайте jsfiddle демку, я поправлю тогда чтобы не тормозило.

Comment: eicto, спасибо за подсказку, код отформатировал.Буду оч признателен за помощь,а то не совсем ясна идея с clearTimeout/setTimeout, в том смылсле когда и какой код запустить через  setTimeou...

Comment: @visionp http://jsfiddle.net/ вот тут сделайте рабочее demo чтобы было видно как тормозит.

Comment: Демо сделал http://jsfiddle.net/visionp/JsNk4/
Вот  только тут тормоза не проявляются, видимо они проявляются тогда когда скрипт работаем в сумме с остальными не моими скриптами на странице. Но все равно если не трудно подскажите саму идею с clearTimeout/setTimeout.

Comment: я посмотрел, clearTimeout не нужен в данном случае, но вот так http://jsfiddle.net/JsNk4/3/

вся проблема с вашим скриптом, что он  напихивал заданий для события.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, есть способ вашу таблицу разбить на две части - ту, что всегда видна и ту, что не всегда видна. Для той части, что всегда видна, время от времени применяйте и отменяйте position: fixed.